# how to use initialize value we obtained from the url in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React front end project. I want to take parameter from the URL and save it in another variable.

```
const id={match.params.pid};
```

It's not working properly. Can anyone help me?

I want to store the parameter in a local variable

```
DtaDisplay1 = ({match}) => {
    return (
      const id={match.params.pid};
      <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>)
}
```

Here I am passing the value in URL:

```
<Route path="/dta/:pid" component={this.DtaDisplay1}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try storing the id in a variable before the return statement.

```
DtaDisplay1 = ({match}) => {
    const id=match.params.pid;
    return (
      <div>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. but i tried this before. this is not working for me. it showing error that  ',' expected. @Harshil shah

Comment: Can you re check after the current Edit? According to react-router docs you can access the id using `match.params.id` and not `{match.params.id}` @Gauranga

Comment: This will also help you store the id in a variable and use it at different places within the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example [here](https://codepen.io/hardik-chaudhary/pen/QoXYwZ). It will show you that how to use parameters of url with React router.

In this pen, see the About component route, about link and About component it self. I think you will definitely get the solution from this.

```
const About = (props)=>{
  const id = props.match.params.aboutId;
  return <div>
    <h1>About - || id = {id}</h1>
    <p>This is about</p>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the code snippets I find something or the else missing. Please try using the below snippet and see if it works. This should be the right way to do it

```js
DtaDisplay1 = ({match}) => {
    const id = match.params.pid;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{id}</h1>
      </div>
    );
}
```